# I am attempting to make a histogram in R, but my aes() object is not being found?

Tags: r, object, histogram

I am attempting to make a histogram in R, but my aes() object is not being found. This is my code:

```
Plot_Laptop <- ggplot(AgeFromFirstDataSet,aes_(Age)+geom_histogram())
```

I am getting this error message:

> "Error in aes_(Age) : object 'Age' not found"

I have typed the object correctly and can see it in the dataset, which is there in my global environment. Why is it unable to find Age, and how do I make R find the objects I am trying to utilise?

Thank You.

Comment: In addition to the error of using aes_ your example above also has misplaced a parenthesis.

Comment: Use `aes()` instead of `aes_()` and move the last parenthesis before the `+`:   
`Plot_Laptop <- ggplot(AgeFromFirstDataSet, aes(Age)) + geom_histogram()`

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to produce that error:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes_(carat)) +
     geom_histogram()
#Error in aes_(carat) : object 'carat' not found
```

You should not be using `aes_`. Instead use `aes`

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
     geom_histogram()
#`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
# and the expected plot.
```